# Converting df to csv format, without creating a file

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am creating a process to converting an API data into a df.

My problem is:

The data just appears correct after exporting to a csv file, using '    df.to_csv("df.csv", sep=','). If I don't do that, the first column appears a big data list.

Is there a way to do this process of convert to csv format without creating an external file ?

[image: Df without converting to csv format]

[image: after Csv format]

Comment: A bit too vague without a reproducible example, but I'd initially suggest that you could construct a temporary file that will be removed by the operating system. In R, see `?tempfile`. Something similar exists for python, though I'm currently drawing a blank.

Comment: Do you want to assign `csv` format content to a variable in memory? What exactly do you mean by _without creating an external file_

Comment: I mean, creating a dataframe in the second picture format, without having to create a external csv file.

Comment: You have already imported your file in R and you want to convert the list (picture1) you obtain from your original file into a data frame (picture 2)?

Comment: Exactly. But I just got this, when I convert into csv file. Is there a direct way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) of `DataFrame.to_csv`:

```
path_or_buf : string or file handle, default None

File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a 
string.
```

So simply doing:

```
csv_string = df.to_csv(None, sep=",")
```

Gives you a string containing a `csv` representation of your dataframe without creating an external file.